# Detect clusters of tokens on an x y grid

Tags: unity, c#, grid

Ok, so I have a two dimensional grid working on integer x and y coordinates.

Each of this coordinates can have one and only one token on it.

The tokens have the capability of check and return an adjacent token given a direction in which to search (they'll return null in case nothing is there)

I now need an algorithm to check the grid for clusters of 3 or more adjacent tokens and add each cluster to a dedicated variable (meaning than, instead of just stopping after return one cluster, it needs to check for all clusters on the board)

I've been thinking for a while but came out with nothing, any help?

Comment: Can you explain clusters more?  Is a cluster just a line, a connected set including up down left right? Do diagonal tokens count as the cluster?

Comment: Groups of tokens that are adjacent to each other not including diagonals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finding 3+ is easy if you realize that regardless of their respective positions to each other, at least one of them will *always* have at least two neighbors.  Once you've found a location in the grid that is part of a triplet, use a floodfill algorithm to locate the entire cluster.

You won't be able to assign this to a "dedicated variable" but you *can* store the result into a list, then return the list.

I'd suggest that the list contains only the markers that detect that they are part of a cluster (i.e. only the tokens that have 2+ identical neighbors) and then working from that list removing duplicates (any token that has a matching neighbor that is also in the list can be removed, and for every removed token, all of *its* neighbors can also be removed).  This will produce a list that contains 1 entry for each cluster (or very close to it).

Although if you're interested in having the *whole cluster* represented, then do the reverse, for each token, add all of its matching neighbors, rather than removing.

Floodfill, as a recursive algorithm, is really simple (pseudocode from Wikipedia):

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

You'd not be altering your map, but the basic process would be similar: for each token perform the action on every neighboring token, skipping completed locations and non-matching tokens.